# Indirizzo doesn't recognize street names named after states

Tags: ruby, csv

I have an array being generated from a .CSV file full of addresses, and I need to have it just pull out the street names, followed by  Rd, Road, St, etc. and 
 the RubyGem Indirizzo does this perfectly except it doesn't recognize streets named after states like Missouri Road or Washington Avenue. Anyone have any idea how to get around this?

```
#!ruby.exe
require 'Indirizzo'
require 'csv'

file = "Reports.csv"
begin
  File.open(file, 'r')
rescue
  print "Failed to open #{file}\n"
  exit
end

data_file = File.new(file)
data = [] #initializes array for addresses from .csv
counter=0 #set counter up to allow for different sized files to be used without         
issue

CSV.foreach(data_file, headers: true) do |row|
  data << row.to_hash
  counter+=1
end #goes through .csv one line at a time

data.reject!(&:empty?)

i=0
streets = []
column = "Street Name"

while (i<counter)
  address = data[i][column]
  street_name = address.gsub(/^((\d[a-zA-Z])|[^a-zA-Z])*/, '')
  new_address = Indirizzo::Address.new(street_name, :expand_streets => false)
  streetName = new_address.street
  puts streetName
  i+=1
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Indirizzo doesn't recognize street addresses with names like `Washington`, that is probably a bug and should be reported on [Github](https://github.com/daveworth/Indirizzo/issues). That being said, it looks like the gem hasn't been updated since 2013 so I wouldn't hold my breath for a fix.

In the mean time, the gem [`StreetAddress`](https://github.com/street-address-rb/street-address) seems to be able to parse cases like that. The example that is in the README has the address `1600 Pennsylvania Ave, Washington, DC, 20500`. Furthermore, this gem looks more maintained; it was last updated in 2017.

Comment: Much appreciated!